# How to mock log4net ILog

Tags: c#, unit-testing, log4net

I am using xunit, nsubsitute and autofixture. 
My controller using log4net for logging.

While unit testing the logger throws argument that says something is not set.

Unit test:

```
   [Frozen] ILog logger // v1
   var logger = Substitute.For<ILog>(); // v2
```

Controller:

```
 private readonly log4net.ILog _logger;
 _logger.Error(..); // here the error shows
```

Comment: Are you have setting log4net in file config?

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Personally I'd wrap the log4net stuff behind your own interface and mock your interface instead. For two reasons, 1, it makes it easier to changing the logging implementation if log4net doesn't work out. 2, you can easily mock your own interface instead of attempting to mock a 3rd party library.

Comment: Can you share the exact error?